# How to use a variable as value for a prop in a component call for React?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to use a variable as a value for a props name, but cannot seem to make it work. Is it even possible or do I need an extra step?

I have tried to use just the normal call:

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const name = "Lister";
    return <h1>Hi there, {this.props.firstName}!</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting firstName=name />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

also tried back-ticks

```
<Greeting firstName=`${name}' />
```

and even double curly's

```
<Greeting firstName={{name}} />
```

I thought it would be pretty straight forward and expected the variable to pass simply, however, that is not the case. Any suggestions?

Comment: ReactDOM.render(
<Greeting firstName='{name}' />, document.getElementById('app')
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the correct way. You have declared your constant inside the `render` function.
But the scope of the function ends before you are using it.

Try

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting firstName="Lister" />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Or declaring the constant in the global scope(before defining your class)

Then you can use curly braces to get the result:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeting firstName={name} />, 
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, placing it outside the class worked!  No idea why I was down voted for not knowing though, stack is a pretty rough place.

Answer (score -1):

`const name = "Lister";` shouldn't be declared in the `Greeting` component.

Try putting the `Greeting` component in a separate file. Import it into the file where you are calling `ReactDOM.render()` using `import {Greeting} from './path/to/greeting'`

Then add

```
  <Greeting firstName='Lister' />, 
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

or if you want to place `'Lister'` in a variable:
`let name = 'Lister'` somewhere in the file where you call `ReactDOM.render()`

```
  <Greeting firstName={name} />, 
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, placing it outside of the class component works, however, the placing it in another file was not really needed