# How do you pass a variable to an href with NextJS/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, tsx

I can't find a good example in NextJS/Typescript to pass a variable into the href string. member.id is a variable and I want to href to turn into something like '/patients/123456'.

```
  <Tr key={member.id}>
    <Td>
      <HStack spacing="3">
        <Box>
          <Link as={NextLink} href='/patients/{member.id}'  fontWeight="medium">
            {member.first_name} {member.last_name}
          </Link>
```

Comment: `href='…'` is a fixed string. Use `href={…}` for an expression, like a string concatenation or a template literal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable as value for a prop in a component call for React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782267/how-to-use-a-variable-as-value-for-a-prop-in-a-component-call-for-react)

Answer (score 2):

Try using template strings. They'll let you plug in variables into strings. The format is like so:

```
const str1 = 'hello';
const str2 = 'world';
const helloWorld = `${str1} ${str2}`;  // 'hello world'
```

So, for your example:

```
<Link as={NextLink} href={`/patients/${member.id}`}  fontWeight="medium">
    {member.first_name} {member.last_name}
</Link>
```

Note the curly braces, since JSX requires them.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! href={`/patients/${member.id}`}